# SQL Server mirroring for more than 10 databases

Tags: sql-server

I have SQL Server instance that has more than 40 databases and I want to make mirroring to another instance server.

But when I read about mirroring I find this restriction:

> On a 32-bit system, database mirroring can support a maximum of about 10 databases per server instance because of the numbers of worker threads that are consumed by each database mirroring session, for 64-Bit Operating system you can mirror more than 10 databases depending on the number of processors and worker threads.

**Question**

How can I make mirroring for all my databases? Or, what I need as a servers equipment to make mirroring for all my 40+ databases?

Answer (score 2):

Database Mirroring is a legacy technology that has been superseded by [AlwaysOn Availability Groups](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/availability-groups/windows/overview-of-always-on-availability-groups-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15)

> **Maximum number of availability groups and availability databases per computer:**
>
> The actual number of databases and availability groups you can put on
>   a computer (VM or physical) depends on the hardware and workload, but
>   there is no enforced limit. Microsoft has tested up to 10 AGs and 100
>   DBs per physical machine, however this is not a binding limit.
>   Depending on the hardware specification on the server and the
>   workload, you can put a higher number of databases and availability
>   groups on an instance of SQL Server.

[Prerequisites, Restrictions, and Recommendations for Always On availability groups](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/availability-groups/windows/prereqs-restrictions-recommendations-always-on-availability?view=sql-server-ver15)